# Saving excel changes date format to OADate

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm trying to fix a date format problem, while debugging the code, the date format is correct, and exports correct, but when the app is on the server, the date comes with an OADate Format (eg: 45000,334424). I have done some conversions inside the code to transform the OaDate into a normal date, but it still doesn't work. It seems the problem might be while saving the excel file.

Maybe some of the paramenters are wrong there or any desktop config, if you come with any suggestions I will be more than pleased to try them out,

Thank you

```
    excelWorkbook.SaveAs(outputPath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,                         XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```